# Removing substring in string using python?

Tags: python, regex

Have a string containing this

```
\ud83d\ude80
\ud83c\udfb0
\ud83d\udd25
```

like  sub-strings all of them start from

```
\ud83
```

(telegram emoji) and have different 7 characters after

```
3
```

so trying to remove them with

```
text = re.sub(r'\\ud83\w{7}', '', text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

with no success what i do wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example? Also, note that ``\`` as a literal backslash is not a word char, and cannot be matched with `\w`. You may consider a `\S`, non-whitespace shorthand character class.

Comment: There's no point in using `re.MULTILINE` if the regex doesn't contain `^` or `$`.

Comment: `\w` won't match a backslash character.

Comment: \S still not work, looking on results code provided i wondering maybe it is something about raw string

Comment: I think python does not see those characters this is something about raw strings (sorry i cant provide working example as it is part of function that depend on too many import that you not willing to pip install anyway and i too new to programing to write it standalone as i got this strings from telethon bot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not dealing with 12 characters here. These seem to be only 2 unicode characters, which are not printable by python and therefore displayed in their escaped form.

```
re.sub(r"[\ud83d\ud83c]\S", "", text)
```

You could create the character class `[\ud83d\ud83c]` manually (adding every allowed starting character) or you find a way to do this programmatically.

Comment: any idea on how to convert them to 12characters to get rid of them by pattern?

Comment: My pattern already matches the example text of the question. If the emoji really can start with every variation of \ud83, you could add them all to the character class. These are only 16 at most. `0-9` and `a-f`:  `[\ud830\ud831 and so on]`. The second part of the emoji is already matched by the `\S`. @someNameJustToAnswer

Answer (score 0):

I think that, if you're trying to remove *everything* after your telegram emoji code, `\w` won't catch the `\` character.

Try

```
text = re.sub(r'\\ud83[\w\\]{7}', '', text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

which is telling the regex to look for 7 characters which could either be alpharnumeric or the `\`.

Comment: Why are you also matching comma and space?

Comment: Because I haven't looked at regex syntax in a while and thought it worked like a Python list. Thanks for catching that!